# ntile function not working in latest version of R

Tags: r, percentile

My data is

```
my_basket <- data.frame(ITEM_GROUP = c("Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy"), 
                       ITEM_NAME = c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Carrot","Potato","Brinjal","Raddish","Milk","Curd","Cheese","Milk","Paneer"),
                       Price = c(100,80,80,90,65,70,60,70,25,60,40,35,50,120))
```

I would like to calculate a column for percentiles using the ntile function

```
df1 = mutate(my_basket, percentile_rank = ntile(my_basket$Price,100))
```

It should give me a dataframe that looks like correct_df

```
correct_df<- data.frame(ITEM_GROUP = c("Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy"), 
                       ITEM_NAME = c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Carrot","Potato","Brinjal","Raddish","Milk","Curd","Cheese","Milk","Paneer"),
                       Price = c(100,80,80,90,65,70,60,70,25,60,40,35,50,120),
                       percentile_rank=c(86,65,72,79,43,51,29,58,1,36,15,8,22,93))
```

But instead I get a dataframe that looks like wrong_df

```
wrong_df<- data.frame(ITEM_GROUP = c("Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy"), 
                        ITEM_NAME = c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Carrot","Potato","Brinjal","Raddish","Milk","Curd","Cheese","Milk","Paneer"),
                        Price = c(100,80,80,90,65,70,60,70,25,60,40,35,50,120),
                        percentile_rank=c(13,10,11,12,7,8,5,9,1,6,3,3,4,14))
```

This issue has only come up since I updated my R version to 4.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an R issue but seems to be an issue with `dplyr` 1.0.0 as mentioned in [this open GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5387). See the difference in the output of two functions taken from there.

```
ntile_083(my_basket$Price,100)
#[1] 86 65 72 79 43 51 29 58  1 36 15  8 22 93
ntile_100(my_basket$Price,100)
#[1] 13 10 11 12  7  8  5  9  1  6  3  2  4 14
```

You can use `ntile_083` to get the previous functionality for now.